# Using SQL to determine the number of different customers who have placed an order for books

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on this assignment in Oracle and the question states "Determine the number of different customers who have ordered a book by an author or co-written by John Doe?" Ultimately it's suppose to look like this when completed.

```
COUNT DISTINCTCUSTOMER
-----------------------
5
```

My SQL query looks like this which is getting me nowhere.

```
SELECT customers
FROM books
where author John Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your data model - use COUNT DISTINCT, e.g:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer)
FROM books
WHERE author = 'John Doe'
```

Comment: Chris,I will try this out at the first chance I get. Thank you very much.